# How to create a texture at the players position and then leave it there XNA?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

I have a game with an *almost* complete player class, but here's my issue. When I press control + K  the player commits suicide (intended). Now, when he dies, it spawns a blood spatter at the players position (also intended) now here's the problem, once the player re spawns, the blood spatter DOES stay visible, but now it follows the player around, which is a *little freaky if you ask me*

So here is the main code:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
  using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;

  namespace Teir_Tactical_2A
  {
         public class Player
     {
    Random random = new Random();
    public Texture2D playerunarmed;
    public Texture2D playerM1911;
    public Texture2D bloodspatter2;
    public Texture2D playerM4;
    public KeyboardState keyState;
    public SpriteFont Font1;
    public KeyboardState oldKeyboardState;
    public Vector2 playerPosition;
    public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    public float Angle { get; set; }
    public float AngularVelocity { get; set; }
    public Vector2 playerVelocity = Vector2.One;
    public bool M1911;
    public bool M4;
    String[] strs = new String[] { "You suicided. Way to go Genius.", "I saw your limbs blow off with that one.", "Click to Respawn", "HAHAHAHAHAHA-Sorry Click to Respawn" };
    String suicideStr;
    public bool player;
    public bool suicide;
    public bool LMBpressed;
    public bool RMBpressed;
    public bool isplayeralive;
    public bool isplayerdead;
    public bool respawnscreen;
    public bool bloodspatter;
    float angle;





    public Player(ContentManager content, Vector2 location)
    {
        this.playerunarmed = content.Load<Texture2D>("PLAYER");
        this.playerM1911 = content.Load<Texture2D>("PLAYERM1911");
        this.playerM4 = content.Load<Texture2D>("PLAYERM4");
        this.bloodspatter2 = content.Load<Texture2D>("blood");
        playerPosition = location;
        suicideStr = strs[random.Next(strs.Length)];
        M1911 = true;
        M4 = true;
        player = true;
        LMBpressed = false;
        suicide = false; 
        RMBpressed = false;
        isplayeralive = true;
        isplayerdead = false;
        respawnscreen = false;
        bloodspatter = false;
        Font1 = content.Load<SpriteFont>("Font1");
    }


    public void Update()
    {
        MouseState curMouse = Mouse.GetState();

        if (bloodspatter == true)
        {
            blood();
        }

        if (suicide == true)
        {
            suicided();
        }

        if (isplayeralive == true)
        {
            alive();
        }

        if (isplayerdead == true)
        {
            dead();
        }

        if (M1911 == true)
        {
            armedM1911();
        }

        if (M4 == true)
        {
            armedM4();
        }
        if (player == true)
        {
            unarmed();
        }
        if (LMBpressed == true)
        {
            LMBpressedA();
        }
        if (RMBpressed == true)
        {
            RMBpressedA();
        }

        Vector2 mouseLoc = new Vector2(curMouse.X, curMouse.Y);

        Vector2 direction = mouseLoc - playerPosition;

        angle = (float)(Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X));

        if (curMouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            LMBpressed = true;

        }
        if (curMouse.RightButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            RMBpressed = true;
        }

        keyState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (isplayeralive == false && LMBpressed == true)
        {
            isplayeralive = true;
            isplayerdead = false;
            suicide = false;
            suicideStr = strs[random.Next(strs.Length)];
        }


        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftControl) && keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.K))
        {
            isplayeralive = false;
            isplayerdead = true;
            bloodspatter = true;
            suicide = true;

        }

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D1))
        {

            M1911 = false;
            M4 = false;
            player = true;

        }
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D2))
        {
            M1911 = true;
            player = false;

        }
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D3))
        {
            M4 = true;
            M1911 = false;
            player = false;

        }





        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            playerPosition.X += playerVelocity.X + 1;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
            playerPosition.X -= playerVelocity.X + 1;

        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            playerPosition.Y -= playerVelocity.Y + 1;
        if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
            playerPosition.Y += playerVelocity.Y + 1;
    }


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        {

            Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, playerunarmed.Width, playerunarmed.Height);
            Vector2 origin = new Vector2(playerunarmed.Width / 2, playerunarmed.Height / 2);

            if (M1911 == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(playerM1911, new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y, playerunarmed.Width, playerunarmed.Height), null, Color.White, angle + 90, new Vector2(86, 88), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
            }

            if (suicide == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(Font1, suicideStr, new Vector2(10, 670), Color.Red);  
            }


            }
            if (bloodspatter == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(bloodspatter2, new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y, bloodspatter2.Width, bloodspatter2.Height), Color.White);
            }



            if (player == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(playerunarmed, new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y, playerunarmed.Width, playerunarmed.Height), null, Color.White, angle + 90, new Vector2(86, 88), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
            }
            if (M4 == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(playerM4, new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y, playerunarmed.Width, playerunarmed.Height), null, Color.White, angle + 90, new Vector2(86, 88), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

            }
            if (LMBpressed == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(Font1, "LMB PRESSED (shot taken prototype)", new Vector2(1000, 22), Color.GreenYellow);
            }
            if (RMBpressed == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(Font1, "RMB PRESSED (grenade thrown prototype)", new Vector2(968, 34), Color.Red);
            }
            if (RMBpressed == true && LMBpressed == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(Font1, "If you are seeing this, the mouse is functioning correctly", new Vector2(810, 45), Color.Black);
            }
        spriteBatch.End();
    }




    public void armedM1911()
    {
        M1911 = true;
        M4 = false;
        player = false;

    }
    public void armedM4()
    {
        M4 = true;
        M1911 = false;
        player = false;
    }
    public void unarmed()
    {
        M1911 = false;
        M4 = false;
    }
    public void LMBpressedA()
    {
        LMBpressed = false;
    }
    public void RMBpressedA()
    {
        RMBpressed = false;
    }
    public void alive()
    {
        M1911 = false;
        player = true;
        M4 = false;
        respawnscreen = false;
    }
    public void dead()
    {
        M1911 = false;
        player = false;
        M4 = false;
        respawnscreen = true;
    }

    public void blood()
    {
        bloodspatter = true;
    }

    public void suicided()
    {
        suicide = true;
    }

}
```

}

Here is where I THINK the problem is (95% sure) I need to get the players coordinates and set them as the location for the bloodspatter (and spawn more if necessary).

```
       if (bloodspatter == true)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(bloodspatter2, new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y, bloodspatter2.Width, bloodspatter2.Height), Color.White);
            }
```

Its probably because of the way I used the `playerPosition` as the `X/Y` coordinates, but I don't know how to tell it to *get them first* and then set the *bloodspatters* location to where the player suicided.

EDIT: It appears that theres a misunderstanding, I *Don't* want the blood texture to disappear, I want it to *Stay* where the player last died (in this case, suiciding, until I can add bullets which call it) Basically, performance is not a problem as its a very low res texture, and in addition I only want them to disappear if the game is closing or the level is changing (not an issue here)

Comment: Do you ever reset `bloodspatter` back to false when the player respawns? Also, remember that the draw is being called every draw cycle and will just take the propertied of the player position every time.

Comment: @SchautDollar wouldn't that cause the texture to dissappear? I'm not at home right now, so I can't get on to test it.

Comment: Yes, Davor Mlinaric Has the right idea. I'm assuming you want the blood splatters to fade away, otherwise you could have a ton of them. Basically, create another class for blood splatter and when the player dies, create the blood splatter with the location of the dying player. Your player then can keep track on how long that blood splatter has been there and remove it when it wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single blood spot to remain after suicide, you could use add a single Vector2 to your Player class and name it like PlaceOfDeath. Default it to a new Vector2.Zero(); When you die, set the location of your hero to be the new PlaceOfDeath and then use that Vector2 as the drawing point for your sprite.

If you want to draw EVERY place your player has died, you could create a List of Vector2s (List) and call it PlacesOfDeath. Default it to an empty list. When you die, set the location of your hero with a PlacesOfDeath.Add({Vector2 Location of Hero}).

Then in your draw code you could iterate over each Vector2 in the PlacesOfDeath list and draw the blood spatter on each place.

So now to the code

For single blood placement -

Add to your class properties / members declarations:

> private Vector2 placeOfDeath = new Vector2.Zero();

Add to your suicide method,

> placeOfDeath = playerPosition;

Change your if(bloodsplatter == true) conditional codeblock in the Draw method:

> spriteBatch.Draw(bloodspatter2, new Rectangle((int)placeOfDeath.X, (int)placeOfDeath.Y, bloodspatter2.Width, bloodspatter2.Height), Color.White);

For multiple blood spots

Add to your class properties / members declarations:

> private List placesOfDeath = new List();

Add to your suicide method,

> placesOfDeath.Add(playerPosition);

Change your if(bloodsplatter == true) conditional codeblock in the Draw method:

> foreach(Vector2 placeOfDeath in placesOfDeath){
>
> spriteBatch.Draw(bloodspatter2, new Rectangle((int)placeOfDeath.X, (int)placeOfDeath.Y, bloodspatter2.Width, bloodspatter2.Height), Color.White);
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

do not connect player with bloodsplater. make it independed. so when player die just call function that will create blood at current player position.

create a list where you will store all bloodsplatter, and then just add new bloodsplatter into that list. and then in gamplay class call draw and update for this list.

pseudo:

```
splater (position as vector)
splaterlist inherit list of splater
- sub add new splater(position)
- sub update each splater, add duration, fade out
- sub draw each splater

player class
if player die add new splater into splaterlist

gameplay class
update player, draw player
update splaterlist, drawsplaterlist
```

Comment: I think I understand what your saying here, but it needs refining a little, I don't want it to disappear, but I think your Idea should work.

Comment: it will not disapear, it will allways stay at screen. but now you have control over every instance of blood. you can add slight increase of scale, to simulate bleeding. but depend on number of enemies you have on screen, maybe will be good to fade out.. because whole screen could go red very soon. :)